# Remove size label from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I created the following plot in `R` with the library `ggplot2`

```
p_cd = c(0.01,0.15,0.5,0.7,0.9)
p_cr = c(0.01,0.15,0.5,0.7,0.9)

data = as.data.frame(expand.grid(p_cd,p_cr))
data = cbind(data,rep(NA,dim(data)[1]))
colnames(data) = c('p_cd','p_cr','weights')
weights = runif(sum(seq(1,4,by=1)),0,5)
u = 1
for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  if(data[i,1]>data[i,2]){
    data[i,3] = weights[u]
    u = u + 1
  }
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data[!is.na(data[,3]),], aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr, color=weights, size = 3)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

However, what I would like to do is to remove the label size from the plot, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `scale_size_continuous(guide = "none")`.

```r
ggplot(data[!is.na(data[,3]),], aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr, color=weights, size = 3)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_continuous(guide = "none")
```

[image]

Or ... if you want the legend but not the title, then

```r
ggplot(data[!is.na(data[,3]),], aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr, color=weights, size = 3)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_continuous(name = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should put `size` out of `aes`:

```
ggplot(data[!is.na(data[,3]),]) +
  geom_point(aes(x=p_cd, y=p_cr, color=weights), size = 3)
```

[image]